# Can every SPARQL query be expressed as a GraphQL query?

Tags: graph

The question is really formulated in the title :-)

I am working on an RDF project but I want to make it as easy as possible to interact with the API. Therefor GraphQL seems the most likely.

**UPDATE:

[Got an answer on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Can-every-SPARQL-query-be-expressed-as-a-GraphQL-query/).**

Answer (score -1):

We are currently working on a GraphQL library to query a SPARQL Endpoint according to an OWL schema. It will be the main API access point for the DATAtourisme, french government project to handle and share touristic open data.

Contact me to tell me more about your project, i will tell you if the library can fit your needs.

Comment: This should have been posted as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Sorry, i can't post any comment, my reputation is less than 50.